# Opertion performance between ArrayList or single String

Tags: java, string, performance, arraylist

Performance wise, is it better to use `ArrayList`s to store a list of values, or a `String` (using concat/+)? Intuitively, I think `String`s would perform better since it'd likely use less overhead than ArrayLists but I haven't been able to find anything online.

Also, the entries wouldn't be anything too large (~10).

Comment: Depends what you mean with "store". Store where?

Comment: An array list has a series of buckets, each of which can be looked up in constant time.  A string of 10 terms, on the other hand, would need to be split, or sprinkled with regex potion, to be able to access a single item.  Long story short, you'll do a lot of dancing with the string approach, and relatively little with the array list.

Comment: Depends on the values too. A list of pojo is easier to go through (in a program) than a big string of csv data

Comment: For 10 entries, it's not going to make any difference -> use what's easiest and more readable -> ArrayList.

Comment: Use the appropriate data structure so that it is easy to maintain.  Later, if performance becomes an issue then profile the code to see what could be optimized.

Comment: @marstran I'm not sure I understand your question. By store I mean adding elements to an arraylist or concatenating a string.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I expected that. But thought it'd be worth the performance?

Comment: @assylias Yes, you're right. I'll stick with an ArrayList then. Thanks!

Comment: @StaticCrazee Ok. Then using a `List` is certainly the way to go. My point was that "store" could mean storing to a database, a file or something else.

Comment: @GhostCat Already did :) Thanks again

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ArrayList operations**

You can *get* a value from an `ArrayList` in O(1) and *add* a value in O(1).
Furthermore, `ArrayList` has already build-in operations that help you to retrieve and add elements.

**String operations**

*Concatenation*: With a concat and slice operations, it will be worst. A String is roughly speaking arrays of characters. For example, "Hello" + "Stack" can be represented as array `['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']` and array `['S', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k']`.
Now, if you want to concat these two `String`, you will have to combined all elements of both arrays. It will give you an array of length 10. Therefore, the concatenation - or creating your new char array - is operation in `O(n + m)`.

Worst, if you are concatening n `String`, you will have a complexity of `O(n^2)`.

*Splitting*: the complexity of splitting a String is usually `O(N)` or more. It depends on the regex you will give for the split-operation.

Operations with `String` are often not that readable and can be stricky to debug.

**Long story short**

An `ArrayList` is usually better than operation with `String`. But all depend on your use case.

Comment: Thank you! It makes alot more sense with Big O :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use ArrayList, it stores the references to your object values, and the reference is not big at all, and that's the point to use references. I keep wondering why will you want to store the value inside a String... that's just odd. ArrayList to store values and get them are faster enough, and String implementation, inside uses arrays also... so... Use ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Java performance doesn't come out of "clever" Java source code.

It comes out of the JIT doing a good job at runtime.

You know what the JIT needs to be able to do a good job?

- code that looks like code everybody else is writing (it is *optimised* to produce optimal results for the sort of code everybody else writes)
- many thousands of method invocations.

Meaning: the JIT decides whether it makes sense to re-compile code. When the JIT decides to do so, and only then, you want to make sure it can do that.

"Custom" clever java source code ideas, such as what you are proposing here might achieve the opposite.

Thus: don't invent a clever strategy to mangle values into a String. Write simple, human understandable code that uses a List. Because Lists are the concept that Java offers here.

The only exception would be: if you experience a *real* performance bottleneck, and you did good profiling, and then you figure: the list isn't good enough, then you would start making experiments using other approaches. But I guess that didn't happen yet. You *assume* you have a performance problem, and you *assume* that you should fix it that way. Simply wrong, a waste of time and energy.

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely helpful. As a single developer, I never thought the compiler would punish me for using strange code. I'd have accepted this had you answered sooner :)

Comment: One can accept other answers, but that feels pretty bad for the other guy. And I made good reputation this week, so I really don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is better choice because String is underneath an array of chars. So every concatenation is just copying the whole old string to a new place, with added new value - time O(n) for each operation.

When you use ArrayList, it has an initial capacity - until it is filled - every add operation is in time O(1). adding new String into ArrayList is only slower when array is full, then it needs to be copied into new place with more capacity. But only references needs to be moved, not the whole Strings - which is way faster than moving whole Strings.

You can even make ArrayList performance better by setting initial capacity when you know how many element do you have:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(elementsCount);
```